# using namespace in php project

Tags: php, phpunit, slim

I have in this php project using the Slim framework with two folder's - `src` and `test`.
inside thie `src` folder there is a `classes` folder with the following class :

```
<?php
use Slim\Slim;

class Website {
  public $siteId;
  protected $db = null;

  function __construct($siteId) {
    $this->siteId = $siteId;
  }

  function getDbh() {
    if ($this->db === null){
      $this->db = Slim::getInstance()->db;
    }
    return $this->db->getConnection();
  }

  function getPlacements() {
    $placements = array();
    $DBH = $this->getDbh();
    $query = "select placement from rules where site='{$this->siteId}' group by placement";
    $STH = $DBH->query($query);
    $placements = $STH->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);

    return $placements;
  }
}
```

What i want to do it's to create test for this class , and for that i need  to get the structure of the database from the query, but i cant figure out how to do that. i tried to create this `WebsiteTest.php` file inside the `test` folder :

```
<?php
use Slim\slim;

require dirname(__FILE__).'/../src/vendor/autoload.php';

class WebsiteTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    public function testWebsite_init()
    {
            $dummy = new Website('1232');
            $dummy->getDbh();
            var_dump($dummy);
    }

}
```

but when i run it i get this error:

```
WebsiteTest::testWebsite_init
Trying to get property of non-object
```

im pretty lost here, but guessing it has to do with the Slim use...any help please??

Comment: Which version of Slim are you using?

Comment: Your use statement isn't pointing to the Website class, you can either change that to be `use \Slim\Slim\Website` or change your new class statement to this `... new Slim\Website(...`.